# Undoing a squashing commits by using a backup branch

Tags: git, github, rebase, pull-request

How can you push to a pull-request from a different branch?

Situation:

1. I have pull-request on github and local branch that tracks it. I
   created a backup local branch, I squashed some commits on original
   local branch, I push to pull-request.
2. I realize I actually didn't have to squash them.
3. Now, how can I push from that backup branch to
   the original pull-request. When I do --force it still doesn't do
   anything?

Comment: Did you try `git branch --set-upstream-to origin/my_branch` first? And after that `git push --force` ? You said `--force` doesn't do anything - is there any error message?

Comment: `git push --force --set-upstream origin <remote pull-request branch name>`
Branch <remote pull-request branch name> set up to track remote branch '<remote pull-request branch name> from 'origin'.
Everything up-to-date

Comment: @Rozart it doesn't push it show everything is up-to-date, although if I check the git log they are different.

Comment: I would additionally try `git push --force origin <backup-branch-name>:<pull-request-branch-name>`

Comment: Thanks so much that works!

Comment: Great, happy to hear that! I have created an answer out of my last comment. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you have different branch names on your local and on your remote.

In that case using

```
git push --force origin <your-local-branch>:<remote-target-branch>
```

Should overwrite the `remote-target-branch` with the current state of `your-local-branch`.